# In Identity Server 4, I have a User's identity but 0 Claims

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, identityserver4

I have an identity server, a JavaScript client, and an API. All have been configured so that Authentication and Authorization are working as expected. I am now attempting to load the current user by id (the sub claim) in my API. The problem is that the `User.Claims` enumeration is empty in all of my controllers.

I have decoded the bearer token I am sending with each request and have confirmed I have a `sub` claim. Is there some additional configuration needed in my API to receive these claims?

### Decoded JWT

```
{
  "nbf": 1510436170,
  "exp": 1510439770,
  "iss": "https://localhost:44300",
  "aud": [
    "https://localhost:44300/resources",
    "mycustom.api"
  ],
  "client_id": "mycustom.web",
  "sub": "c92cc2bc-d063-49d6-a36e-f6340796df15",
  "auth_time": 1510435257,
  "idp": "local",
  "scope": [
    "openid",
    "profile",
    "mycustom.api"
  ],
  "amr": [
    "pwd"
  ]
}
```

### API Configuration

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<BrewSwapDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.Authority = "https://localhost:44300";
            options.ApiName = "mycustom.api";
        });

    services.AddMvc();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.UseCors(builder =>
        builder.AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyOrigin());

    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

### Client Configuration

On the SPA client I am using `angular-auth-oidc-client`. Again, I am able to inspect the bearer token in each request and can see the `sub` claim I need. See the decoded JWT above.

```
let oidcConfig = new OpenIDImplicitFlowConfiguration()
oidcConfig.stsServer = "https://localhost:44300";
oidcConfig.redirect_url = "https://localhost:44302";
oidcConfig.client_id = 'mycustom.web';
oidcConfig.response_type = 'id_token token';
oidcConfig.scope = 'openid profile mycustom.api';
oidcConfig.post_logout_redirect_uri = "https://localhost:44302";
oidcConfig.start_checksession = false;
oidcConfig.silent_renew = true;
oidcConfig.silent_renew_offset_in_seconds = 0;
oidcConfig.startup_route = '/home';
oidcConfig.auto_userinfo = true;
oidcConfig.log_console_warning_active = true;
oidcConfig.log_console_debug_active = true;
oidcConfig.max_id_token_iat_offset_allowed_in_seconds = 10;
oidcConfig.storage = localStorage;
```

### API Controller

```
public class ExampleController : Controller
{
    private readonly MyDbContext _context;

    public ExampleController(MyDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Example> GetExamples()
    {
        var test = User.Claims;
        return _context.Examples;
    }
}
```

You can see below that an identity was found... 
[image: Identity found]

but it has 0 claims.
[image: No claims]

Comment: Did you include get claims from user info endpoint to true ?

Comment: `app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication` is obsolete. Where does `getClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint` go now?

Comment: Please share the client configuration and did you write any code on the IdentityServer4 side to populate the claims?

Comment: @aaronR API and client config added. No I have no code adding claims in my id server. I only need the default basic claims. Specifically, `sub`.

Comment: Can you share one of your controllers in the API where you try to read the sub claim?

Comment: @aaronR Added with screenshots.

Comment: What happens when you add the [Authorize] attribute to the GetExample method? (Just to make sure authentication is set correctly.)

Comment: @aaronR good call. I found that it was attempting to redirect to login on my API, not id server. Comparing with master I found that `services.AddIdentity()` in API `ConfigureServices` was the culprit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**API Setup correction:**

This is the correct code for your `ConfigureServices` method.

The AddIdentity is not needed since the information is provided by the claims that come from the IdentityServer4.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.Authority = "https://localhost:44300";
            options.ApiName = "mycustom.api";
        });

    services.AddMvc();
}
```

Comment: Hi aaronR, I am facing a similar problem where we have some api in different applications but some API in the same in identity server application. With .net core version 1.x the User claims was found everywhere but after upgrading .net core version to 2.x User claims  are empty. Do you have any idea is there any change/restrictions in making identity server and API in same application in version 2.x?

Comment: @UtpalKumarDas so you have 2 API’s. One hosted in same site as IDSVR 4 and another in a different project/location?

Comment: Hi aaronR thanks for reply, yes, we have some APIs in IDSVR4 project other API's are in different project, in other project /domain we get the user claims but when IDSVR itself has resource there the problems.

Comment: @NastyaScherbakova what version of IdentityServer4 are you using?

Comment: @aaronR 2.5.2 version